# fx.prp.file.name to string

Tags: java, jsp

I'm having trouble understanding one of the guidelines set by my instructor:

•   A public static final String that is assigned the value fx.prp.file.name.  This is the context initialization parameter key for the relative path to the property file /WEB INF/fxCalc.prp

While using the code

```
public static final String codes = "fx.prp.file.name";
```

i get the error

```
    cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable codes
  location: class SimplifiedJSPServlet
```

when i call it from the java file to the jsp file

EDIT:

After this, i have to call it back on a JSP

- Inside of `jspInit` you can use the `getServletContext` method to get a `ServletContext` object. This object is available to all JSPs. The object has a method call `getInitParameter` that allows you to retrieve a `param-valu`e if you give it a `param-name`. The param-name, fx.prp.file.name, should be a
  `public final static String` constant inside of `FxDataModel`. Do not hard-code anything.

It's going to act as a reference, simply surrounding the words in quotes doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

Make it

```
public static final String codes = "fx.prp.file.name";
```

if you want to assign literal value `"fx.prp.file.name"` to reference`codes`

Comment: I wish it were that easy.  Unfortunately when i try to call it back i get a 'cannot find symbol' error

Comment: I get this error when i call codes in my JSP

cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable codes
  location: class SimplifiedJSPServlet
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)